# Storing data in 2 arrays that relate to each other

Tags: c

The title was hard to create but I'll try my best to explain.

So I am trying to create a program that reads a tracefile and uses different time-quantums to get the optimal time to complete all processes.

What I need to do is store the processes in a data structure and the events of each process in a data structure.

Example of a tracefile:

```
process 1 200 {
i/o 100 usb2 1600
i/o 110 hd 1000
exit 400
}

process 2 250 {
i/o 100 hd 1000
exit 500
}
```

This is just an example of a tracefile. What I have tried is storing the process number in an array and the events in an array.

```
#define CHAR_COMMENT            '#'
#define MAXWORD                 20

void parse_tracefile(char program[], char tracefile[])
{
//  ATTEMPT TO OPEN OUR TRACEFILE, REPORTING AN ERROR IF WE CAN'T
    FILE *fp    = fopen(tracefile, "r");

    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("%s: unable to open '%s'\n", program, tracefile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char line[BUFSIZ];
    int  lc     = 0;
//  READ EACH LINE FROM THE TRACEFILE, UNTIL WE REACH THE END-OF-FILE

    char devices[MAX_DEVICES]; // Store the device names
    char device_size[MAX_DEVICES]; // Store the size of each device
    char processes[MAX_PROCESSES]; // Store the processes
    int process_time[MAX_PROCESSES]; // Store the time of each process
    int data_transfer[MAX_EVENTS_PER_PROCESS]; // Store the data transfer amount
    char event[MAX_PROCESSES][MAX_EVENTS_PER_PROCESS];

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL) {
        ++lc;

//  COMMENT LINES ARE SIMPLY SKIPPED
        if(line[0] == CHAR_COMMENT) {
            continue;
        }

//  ATTEMPT TO BREAK EACH LINE INTO A NUMBER OF WORDS, USING sscanf()
        char    word0[MAXWORD], word1[MAXWORD], word2[MAXWORD], word3[MAXWORD];
        int nwords = sscanf(line, "%s %s %s %s", word0, word1, word2, word3);

//      printf("%i = %s", nwords, line);

//  WE WILL SIMPLY IGNORE ANY LINE WITHOUT ANY WORDS
        if(nwords <= 0) {
            continue;
        }

//  LOOK FOR LINES DEFINING DEVICES, PROCESSES, AND PROCESS EVENTS
        if(nwords == 4 && strcmp(word0, "device") == 0) {
            // DEVICE FOUND STORE THIS SOMEWHERE
        }

        else if(nwords == 1 && strcmp(word0, "reboot") == 0) {
            system_time = 0;
        }

        else if(nwords == 4 && strcmp(word0, "process") == 0) {
            processes[x] = word1;
            process_time[x] = atoi(word2);
        }

        else if(nwords == 4 && strcmp(word0, "i/o") == 0) {
            //  AN I/O EVENT FOR THE CURRENT PROCESS, STORE THIS SOMEWHERE

        }

        else if(nwords == 2 && strcmp(word0, "exit") == 0) {

            //  PRESUMABLY THE LAST EVENT WE'LL SEE FOR THE CURRENT PROCESS
        }

        else if(nwords == 1 && strcmp(word0, "}") == 0) {
            continue;   //  JUST THE END OF THE CURRENT PROCESS'S EVENTS
        }
        else {
            printf("%s: line %i of '%s' is unrecognized",
                        program, lc, tracefile);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

#undef  MAXWORD
#undef  CHAR_COMMENT
```

What I need to do is if I get processes[0] (which is process 1) I want all the events that are under process 1 in the event[] array. Is this possble? There could be 100's of processes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty adaptation of your code, just to give you an idea.

Processes and events are reallocated one by one which is inefficient (a strategy like `std::vector` in C++ would be better).

I don't know anything about the purpose of the stored information, so I just store strings here (you should adapt to your actual needs).

The main idea is that, if you know a process you will obtain the index-range of its events in the other array.
And if you know an event, you will obtain the index of its process in the other array.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHAR_COMMENT '#'
#define MAXWORD      20

typedef struct
{
  int id;
  int info;
  int event_begin;
  int event_end;
} ProcessInfo;

typedef struct
{
  int process_index; /* optional, for back link */
  char info1[MAXWORD];
  char info2[MAXWORD];
  char info3[MAXWORD];
  char info4[MAXWORD];
} EventInfo;

void
parse_tracefile(const char *program,
                const char *tracefile,
                ProcessInfo **inout_processes,
                int *inout_process_count,
                EventInfo **inout_events,
                int *inout_event_count)
{
  ProcessInfo *processes=*inout_processes;
  int process_count=*inout_process_count;
  EventInfo *events=*inout_events;
  int event_count=*inout_event_count;

  FILE *fp    = fopen(tracefile, "r");

    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("%s: unable to open '%s'\n", program, tracefile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char line[BUFSIZ];
    int  lc     = 0;
//  READ EACH LINE FROM THE TRACEFILE, UNTIL WE REACH THE END-OF-FILE

    // char devices[MAX_DEVICES]; // Store the device names
    // char device_size[MAX_DEVICES]; // Store the size of each device
    // char processes[MAX_PROCESSES]; // Store the processes
    // int process_time[MAX_PROCESSES]; // Store the time of each process
    // int data_transfer[MAX_EVENTS_PER_PROCESS]; // Store the data transfer amount
    // char event[MAX_PROCESSES][MAX_EVENTS_PER_PROCESS];

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL) {
        ++lc;

//  COMMENT LINES ARE SIMPLY SKIPPED
        if(line[0] == CHAR_COMMENT) {
            continue;
        }

//  ATTEMPT TO BREAK EACH LINE INTO A NUMBER OF WORDS, USING sscanf()
        char    word0[MAXWORD], word1[MAXWORD], word2[MAXWORD], word3[MAXWORD];
        int nwords = sscanf(line, "%s %s %s %s", word0, word1, word2, word3);

//      printf("%i = %s", nwords, line);

//  WE WILL SIMPLY IGNORE ANY LINE WITHOUT ANY WORDS
        if(nwords <= 0) {
            continue;
        }

//  LOOK FOR LINES DEFINING DEVICES, PROCESSES, AND PROCESS EVENTS
        if(nwords == 4 && strcmp(word0, "device") == 0) {
            // DEVICE FOUND STORE THIS SOMEWHERE
        }

        else if(nwords == 1 && strcmp(word0, "reboot") == 0) {
            // system_time = 0;
        }

        else if(nwords == 4 && strcmp(word0, "process") == 0) {
            // processes[x] = word1;
            // process_time[x] = atoi(word2);
            ++process_count;
            processes=(ProcessInfo *)realloc(processes,
                                             sizeof(ProcessInfo)*(size_t)process_count);
            processes[process_count-1].id=atoi(word1);
            processes[process_count-1].info=atoi(word2);
            processes[process_count-1].event_begin=event_count;;
            processes[process_count-1].event_end=event_count;;
        }

        else if(nwords == 4 && strcmp(word0, "i/o") == 0) {
            //  AN I/O EVENT FOR THE CURRENT PROCESS, STORE THIS SOMEWHERE
            ++event_count;
            events=(EventInfo *)realloc(events,
                                        sizeof(EventInfo)*(size_t)event_count);
            events[event_count-1].process_index=process_count-1;
            strcpy(events[event_count-1].info1, word0);
            strcpy(events[event_count-1].info2, word1);
            strcpy(events[event_count-1].info3, word2);
            strcpy(events[event_count-1].info4, word3);
            ++processes[process_count-1].event_end;
        }

        else if(nwords == 2 && strcmp(word0, "exit") == 0) {

            //  PRESUMABLY THE LAST EVENT WE'LL SEE FOR THE CURRENT PROCESS
            ++event_count;
            events=(EventInfo *)realloc(events,
                                        sizeof(EventInfo)*(size_t)event_count);
            events[event_count-1].process_index=process_count-1;
            strcpy(events[event_count-1].info1, word0);
            strcpy(events[event_count-1].info2, word1);
            strcpy(events[event_count-1].info3, "");
            strcpy(events[event_count-1].info4, "");
            ++processes[process_count-1].event_end;
        }

        else if(nwords == 1 && strcmp(word0, "}") == 0) {
            continue;   //  JUST THE END OF THE CURRENT PROCESS'S EVENTS
        }
        else {
            printf("%s: line %i of '%s' is unrecognized",
                        program, lc, tracefile);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

  *inout_processes=processes;
  *inout_process_count=process_count;
  *inout_events=events;
  *inout_event_count=event_count;
}

int
main(int argc,
     char **argv)
{
  if(argc!=2)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s file_name\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  ProcessInfo *processes=NULL;
  int process_count=0;
  EventInfo *events=NULL;
  int event_count=0;
  parse_tracefile(argv[0], argv[1],
                  &processes, &process_count,
                  &events, &event_count);

  for(int p=0; p<process_count; ++p)
  {
    const ProcessInfo *process=processes+p;
    printf("process: %d %d\n", process->id, process->info);
    for(int e=process->event_begin; e<process->event_end; ++e)
    {
      const EventInfo *event=events+e;
      printf("  %s %s %s %s\n",
             event->info1, event->info2, event->info3, event->info4);
      if(event->process_index!=p)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "!!!inconsistant process index!!!\n");
      }
    }
  }
  free(processes);
  free(events);
  return 0;
}
```